# Distributed Reactjs routing as in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, url-routing

I am switching from Angular.js to React.js.

In angular, I keep my code strictly compartmentalized. I have one html and one js file for every view. In angular you can have a central routing file or have it broken up and distributed.

For example, If http://example.com*profile is supposed to spin up the profile.html and profile.js, I will have the routing information inside the profile.js file.

I would like to do the same thing in React

Is there a way, for example to have

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
</Router>
```

in the profile.js file and also have

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/widgets" component={Widgets} />
</Router>
```

in the widget.js file?

Can the two co-exist? I am strong believer in separation of concerns for features and it would be nice if the programmer working on the "profile" view would not have to access the same routing file as the programmer working on the "widget" view.

Answer (score 1):

As per react-router-dom 4.0.

You can have the entry point inside the router tag.

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} >
        <Route path="/" component={AppContainer} />
    </Router>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('app')
);
```

and then have base routes being defined in the internal components.

```
<App >
    <Route path="/" component={LoginContainer} />
    <Route path="/login" component={LoginContainer} />
    <Route path="/registration" component={RegistrationContainer} />
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardContainer} />
</App>
```

And so on.

The above snippets are from a react-redux based learning project I did a few weeks ago ( https://github.com/ajzone007/expense-splitter )